# SVN: creating a repo from existing repos directory

Tags: svn

I have a repo containing lots of projects as folders, now I have possibility to separate them. So each directory is actually a separate repo. I dont have access to current servers ssh, so I can't use svnadmin.

The question is: how do I create repos from another repos folder?

Thank you.

Comment: Does new repo exist?

Comment: i can create it. basically on new server i can do anything, but can't do anything at current one.

Answer (score 2):

Use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnsync.html) to make a remote copy of the source repository.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the current server, you cannot preserve the revision history. But you can copy files into new repository and commit.